# How to run bash script in an already created/exisitng VM in GCP using NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have gone through, [Nodejs-GCP-Compute-Github](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-compute) doc and used the sample code to create a new VM and list existing VM using NodeJS and Npm module.

Now I want to connect to my existing VM and run a small bash script to invoke a few commands mostly `git clone` or `curl` to run files in VM.

I couldn't find a method in `@google-cloud/compute` to connect to the exisitng VMs and do some stuff.

Do we have any such method?

Is it possible to do this in some other way using Nodejs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different methods coming to my mind:

1. You could add your public key to the instance, and then connect to it via `ssh` using a node `ssh` library (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys)
2. Set a [startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) for the instance when you are creating it. This can be done by setting the second parameter (config) of `createVM` to something like:

```
{
  os: 'ubunntu',
  metadata: {
    'startup-script': 'your commands'
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, SSH through Nodejs is working. I am connecting to the VM as a new user. Lets assume the VM is already running a Kubernetes server, will the new user be able to access/make changes to it via admin(sudo) commands? or does he/she again need to set PATH(s)/configs and run server?

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on what you mean by the Kubernetes server? You should avoid installing anything on the managed instances of GKE. In case you installed Minikube or any other service through the user, you should also be able to connect to that using your local configs.

Otherwise, yes, kubeconfigs are stored in home paths, so you will need to authenticate again if you authenticated with a different user